# prove exists $\hat E$ defined on the set $Sym^+(\Bbb R^3)$ of symmetric positive definite matrices, such that $E(F)=\hat E(F^TF)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, analysis

Suppose $E:\Bbb R^3\to \Bbb R$ has the property $E(RF)=E(F)$ for every $R\in O(3)$(i.e. $R$ is an orthogonal transformation) and every $F\in \Bbb R^{3\times 3}$.(This means that rotations do not change the energy of a deformed configuration.)

How to prove that there exists a function $\hat E$ defined on the set $Sym^+(\Bbb R^3)$ of symmetric positive definite matrices, such that $E(F)=\hat E(F^TF)$?

I tried to use polar decomposition of a linear transformation. But I do not know how to proceed. Any hint? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint.* Every positive semidefinite matrix has a unique positive semidefinite square root.

Comment: Thanks! I have seen that $F^TF=U^TU$, where U is a symmetric matrix. Then I don't know how to proceed. Could you provide some hint on this?

Comment: Let $g(A)=A^{1/2}$ and $h(F)=F^TF$. You want to make $\hat{E}\circ h=E$. How to construct $\hat{E}$?